# Documentation of software design and architecture

Tags: architecture, documentation

What are the best practices and software tools for documenting software design and architecture for

1. PC based applications based on Java
   or .NET?
2. Embedded Applications based on VxWorks or Embedded Linux or Windows CE?

One tool I have in mind is [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/editions.html). Is it a good choice?

Comment: What is your documentation going to be used for? That will affect the best way to produce it.

Comment: [IBM-Rational software development tools for architecture management](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/offerings/architecture)

Comment: For PC based Java & .NET applications I recommend those 10 free tools : http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2010/10/10-free-standalone-and-easy-to-use-uml.html If you can buy licences for enterprise applications, Enterprise Architect and IBM-Rational are best I think. They are easy-to-use, have nice UI and support reverse engineering and code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much depends upon the purpose of the documentation.  Who is the readership?  Is it to be used in order to drive the development activity, or is it going to be produced in order to provide some historical record?  How large is the team who will be producing/using this documentation?

In our small development team, we find pen/paper and a wiki adequate for most architecture/design documentation.  Some design/architecture decisions can be incorporated into code commentary also (but this obviously makes no sense if the documentation is to be used to drive the development.)  The two specialist tools we often make use of are database diagramming/deployment tools (such as [DBWrench](http://www.dbwrench.com/)) and UML diagramming tools (such as [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/)).

A word of warning: don't produce documentation that will take enormous amounts of effort to maintain or which will not be read by anyone.